# Cannot use WebStorm console in 'live' mode

Tags: webstorm

How do I view/peruse objects in WebStorm in console live mode?

In Chrome, when I am sitting on a breakpoint, I can type something into the console like so :

```
myObject.myVal[0].elem
```

However when I am in WebStorm, sitting on a breakpoint on one of my tests, I open the console, *but I cannot type into the console!!* I cannot see any objects.

It just looks like this :

[image]

I seem to remember it used to be able to do something like this. Is there some setting somewhere that I need to set?

**[..Update..]**

Yes, I was right. It was possible for me to do this in the past :

https://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2014/07/new-live-console-in-javascript-and-node-js-debugger/

This seems not to work for me anymore, or it is broken when running tests.

It makes WebStorm pretty useless for me at the moment.

Answer (score 3):

'Live' mode is not available in Test Frameworks Console; please vote for [WEB-20297](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-20297) to be notified on any progress with this feature